# How to open a file with .0000 extension using matlab?

Tags: matlab

Someone has sent me a dataset with 1.9 GB size and I need to analyze it using Matlab. However it seems that this file extension is not known. Now the question is: how can I open this file in matlab?

Answer (score 0):

Try this http://www.solvusoft.com/en/file-extensions/file-extension-0000/
i think it should help you, this is useful to http://it.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/mathworks-file-extensions.html